# SBCL used memory reports from top and (room) differs

Tags: memory, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I am running SBCL 1.0.51 on a Linux (Fedora 15) 32-bit system (kernel 3.6.5) with 1GB Ram and 256MB swap space.

I fire up `sbcl --dynamic-space-size 125` and start calling a function that makes ~10000 http-requests (using drakma) to an http (couchDB) server and I just format to the standard-output the results of an operation on the returned data.

After each call I do a `(sb-ext:gc :full t)` and then `(room)`. The results are not growing. No matter how many times I run the function, `(room)` reports the same used space (with some ups and downs, but around the same average which does not grow).

BUT: After every time I call the function, top reports that the VIRT and RES amount of the sbcl process keeps growing ,even beyond the 125MB space I told sbcl to ask for itself. So I have the following questions:

1. Why `top` -reported memory keeps growing, while `(room)` says it does not? The only thing I can think of is some leakage through ffi. I am not directly calling out with ffi but maybe some drakma dep does and forgets to free its C garbage.  Anyway I dont know if this could even be an explanation. Could it be something else? Any insights?
2. Why isnt `--dynamic-space-size` honoured?

Comment: best answered by SBCL experts on the SBCL mailing list

Comment: @wvxvw: If it was fragmentation then there would also be an increase in (room) reports, even a small one. How can there be fragmentation with no net memory consumption? As I understand it, fragmentation means I allocate X space then release Y space in such a way Y although free, is unusable (small frags). But in my case, after each call , X equals Y because if they werent equal, room would report some increase

Comment: It's interesting I met the similar problem 5 years after this post. Just wonder did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Wise I really don't remember. I even dont remember if i really solved it or if I just didnt chase it. I didn't ask about it on the SBCL lists, this I remember.